# Is column based table possible in html and/or css

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Given the following structure of HTML:

```
<div class="column">
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell">text</div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
</div>
<div class="column">
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell">multi line text</div>
  <div class="cell"></div>      
</div>
```

Notice that cells are defined inside columns. It's different than regular table where cells are defined per row.

It's easy to make it look like a table if the cells contain only one line of text. But is it possible to achieve cell height adjusting if the cells contain more than one line of text?

So result should look simmilar to table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td><td></td>
  </tr>    
  <tr>
    <td>text</td><td>multi line text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td><td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I think that maybe flexbox would be capable of doing that but I'm not sure if it is possible at all.

Comment: It's definitely possible with flexbox. That being said, tables are for tabular data, so <table> might be the best choice here. Some reading for flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 2):

As @zajd pointed out in his comment, if your intent is displaying tabular data, then you should definitely keep using `<table>` as it was made exclusively for this purpose. Note that Flexbox **was not** made to replace the `<table>` element.

That being said, it is totally possible to "simulate" a table behavior using Flexbox. You could do it as with a little CSS as follow:

```css
.flexbox-table .row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.flexbox-table .row .cell {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox-table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell">text</div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell">multi line text multi line text multi line text multi line text multi line text multi line text multi line text multi line text multi line text multi line text multi line text multi line text</div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell">text</div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This approach would also solve the "multi-line" text issue you asked about.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply it's exactly what I needed. I know that table would be more appropriate but my "table" must support few additional features and using this structure of html really make things easier. I had read flexbox tutorials but somehow I couldn't figure solution on my own.

Comment: I didn't noticed that columns are treated as rows in your solution. If those would be treated as columns then second row of table would contain: text | multi line text | text.

Comment: Yeah. Misspell of the class names. `.col` should be `.row`. Edited.

Comment: Thats not exactly what I expect. I have updated question with more info.